# Is there a difference between Expo Eject and react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I wanted to use In App Purchase and Realm in my project.
expo does not support both.

Use library after ejecting from expo
vs
Use library with react-native

I am concerned about the convenience of expo and the inconvenience of using native modules.

I have no experience and it is difficult to choose.
Please recommend one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose wisely between expo and pure react native app, expo has its own libraries for vast variety of tasks like image picker etc. which we have to install externally in react native app. So if you are sure that your app requirements will be fulfilled by all the libraries expo provides its good to choose expo as it is fast. But some features are not supported in expo as in your case so ultimately you have to eject your expo project, ejecting is very big decision because it is permanent change so should eject only when there is no option. So I would say expo is good for light weighted apps and if you want extravagant features first go through the expo docs for all the features it provides and then only make an app in expo.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say 'extravagant features'. more like 'custom features'.

Comment: Note that we can now "undo" an expo eject. Not such a daunting decision anymore.
https://docs.expo.io/bare/customizing/

Answer (score 1):

There are many modules that do not necessarily have to `expo eject`.

If you really want to use it separately, you'd better learn how to use `Android Studio` or `Xcode`.

The difference between `expo eject` and `react-native` is

1. `react-native` cannot use `expo` modules that can be used for
   projects created with `expo` unless installed separately.
2. The `react-native` version created with `expo` is different from the
   `expo` version.
3. Projects created with `Expo` cannot use the latest `react-native`
   version.The version of `Expo` has been updated until 'Expo' support
   the 'react-native' latest version.

[Modules documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/overview/) available when created with Expo

Whatever you choose is your freedom.